# search for if a specific text (group of string) is present into a file using a batch file

Tags: search, text, batch-file

I am searching for if a specific text (group of string) is present into a file using a batch file. 
Here is what I write but it's not working for text. It's just working for strings (not searching for a text).

```
rem %1 is name of the file whose text is being found
FindStr /C:%2 %1 
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo text %2 is Present
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 echo text %2 is not Present
```

For example If the text "I have breakfast" must be searched into a file which contains "I have breakfast every day", command echo must print this one: 
    " text I have breakfast is present ".

Any help! please.

Answer (score 0):

This file works perfectly.

The command line you need to find your text is

```
yourbatch yourtextfile.txt "I have breakfast"
```

If you execute

```
yourbatch yourtextfile.txt I have breakfast
```

then it will search simply for `I` because SPACE is a delimiter, and in order to search for a space-separated string, you need to `"`quote the string`"`

Same, for that matter, with the filename if your filename contains spaces.

```
yourbatch "your text file.txt" "I have breakfast"


%%1 is "your text file.txt" 
%%2 is "I have breakfast"
```

INCLUDING the quotes.

To remove the quotes, if you want to, you'd use %~2

so - you could `ECHO`

```
ECHO with quotes:%2 and without: %~2
```

ALSO: be careful about

```
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo text %2 is Present
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 echo text %2 is not Present
```

`ECHO` is one of the few commands that does NOT change `errorlevel`. Many DO change it, so for instance if you were to write

If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo Y|find "x" >nul
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 echo text %2 is not Present

then if the `echo Y|find "x" >nul` was found because `errorlevel` from the previous step was 0, then because `echo Y|find "x" >nul` sets errorlevel to 1, the second line would ALSO be executed.

Comment: It's great! Thanks also for details.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you call the script `script.bat "file name" "search string"`:

```
@echo off&setlocal
rem %1 is name of the file whose text is being found
FindStr /C:"%~2" "%~1" >nul
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo text %2 is Present
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 echo text %2 is not Present
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
FindStr /C:"%~2" "%~1" >nul && echo text "I have breakfast is present".
```